# How to set timeout for a block?

Tags: java, timer, profiling

I want to skip a block of statements if it not complete in particular time interval .

For example

```
//block starts 

   while(m3.find())
                {
                 // System.out.println(m3.group());
                    patit = m3.group().replace("(54)", " ");
                    patit = patit.trim();
                     System.out.println("m3");
                }

                while(m4.find() )
                {
                //  System.out.println(m4.group());
                    patno = m4.group().replace("Patent No.: ", " ");
                    patno = patno.replace("Patent No: ", " ");
                    patno = patno.replace("Patent", " ");
                    patno = patno.replace("No.:", " ");
                    patno = patno.replace("No:", " ");
                    patno = patno.replace("Number: ", " ");
                    patno = patno.replace("Number.: ", " ");
                    patno =  patno.trim();
                     System.out.println("m4");
                }
//block ends
```

In the above block , if the block takes more than 20 secs to complete , then "continue;" statement have to be issued ( to skip a for loop, that not given here)..

How to achive this ?

Comment: Far better to ensure it never takes 20 seconds. It shouldn't take a fraction of a second in most cases.

Comment: start a timer at beginning, which sets a boolean at the end.
And change condition to while(find && !lesThen20Seconds)

Comment: I would execute it in a separate thread, and after 20 seconds I would terminate the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider having that block run in a separate thread.  If you can refactor that functionality into a separate class that implements Runnable, have that class run in a thread and have a method called isCompleted().  The class that calls your new class can then do something like this (and I'm just going from memory here and didn't try to compile or run it so sorry if there are any errors):

```
YourNewClass otherObject = new YourNewClass();
Thread t = new Thread(otherObject);
t.start();
int sleepTime = 1000;
int timeLimit = 20000;
while(!otherObject.isCompleted() && time < timeLimit) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        //your error handling code
    }
    time += sleepTime;
}
if(!otherObject.isCompleted()) {
    otherObject.stop();
}
```

This way, the while loop will exit if otherObject completes or if 20 seconds passes.  If 20 seconds passes and it is still running, then you call the stop() method on it.

Of course, the caveat is that according to the official Java documentation, thread scheduling is not technically guaranteed so the thread scheduler could run otherObject's run() method before coming back to the Thread.sleep(sleepTime) above, but it is unlikely if that run() method can take more than 20 seconds.  You could make it even less likely by doing Thread.sleep(100) at the beginning of YourNewClass.run(), which would make it very likely that the thread scheduler would go back to the code above and start the while loop.